# Detect multiple languages in a long text

Tags: java, apache-tika, language-detection

I've got a very long text that's mostly in English but also contains multiple pages worth of text in French, a couple of paragraphs in Greek and a couple of Arabic and German sentences.

So far I've tested both the old "language-detection" [library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/language-detection/) (2011 version, can't find the 2014 one):

```
DetectorFactory.loadProfile(langFolder);
Detector detector = DetectorFactory.create();
detector.append(text);
ArrayList<Language> languages = detector.getProbabilities();
```

... and Apache's [Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) (version 1.25):

```
LanguageDetector detector = new OptimaizeLangDetector();
detector.loadModels();
List<LanguageResult> languages = detector.detectAll(text);
```

The result for the whole text is 99.9something % "en" with both libraries.

I understand that you need a long-ish text sample for the detection to work, so I'm fine with the short Arabic/German sentences not being detected but the Greek/French parts are decently long, so I don't understand why the size of the array is always "1", even though I use the "detect all languages" method.

If I give it only some of the Greek or French text, it detects that it's Greek/French but when I combine them and one part is longer than the other, only the language of that one is output. It seems that both parts have to be approximately the same length to get both languages as a result.

How do I get the result for the other languages too, using either library (but preferably Tika because it's still being updated), even if it's just 0.1%?

Comment: Split the text into chunks / pages and detect on each one?

Comment: Have u tried to use the pdfbox splitter to split the pdf into pages

Comment: No, I haven't tried that yet. Would I then have to run the full above code (or at least `detector.detectAll`) for every page? One thing I'm not sure about with this: Does the detector still act the same? As I said, I already tested giving it less than a page's worth of text with 2 languages but as soon as a paragraph in one language was a bit longer than the other, it still only gave me that language as a result. To get both, both paragraphs have to be about the same length, so detecting within single pages would probably only work if the full page is in a single language.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution to this? I am tinkering around a bit with Lingua on a [separate fork](https://github.com/Marcono1234/tiny-lingua) and have added experimental support for multi-language detection (see also [this comment](https://github.com/pemistahl/lingua/issues/38#issuecomment-1230777577)). It is not production-ready but maybe interesting for you nonetheless. The method is called `LanguageDetector#detectMultiLanguageOf`.

Comment: @Marcono1234 Currently I'm not working on this project anymore but I might start again in the future, so theoretically yes. Please keep me updated and feel free to post an answer if/when your fork is integrated.